# The selected cells are read-only when trying to delete items in DataSheet mode

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

The selected cells are read-only when trying to delete items in DataSheet mode.
Anyone cmae across this as i need to delete my blog list items in bulk i don't want to delete them individually its going to take toooo long.
Thanks

Comment: sorry guys fixed.The approval blog process tied it up to read only :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Mike for the reply.I did try all that but no luck.But i later found out the Approval process built into the blog template was affecting it.As soon as i desable the content approval i could delete it :)

Answer (score 1):

It will come up saying "The selected cells are read only" if you have a multiple lines of text  field that is anything other than "Plain Text" (Such as the body section of a blog post), as Datasheet view has no idea how to deal with HTML etc.

If you want to delete posts in bulk, i would recommend just creating a view that does not contain this field, then selecting the entire row in datasheet view (by clicking the grey tab to the left of the row), right-clicking, and selecting "Delete Rows"